# Failed to attach client certificate during ssl handshake in android

Tags: android, ssl

In my app I need to implement 2way handshake.
Here is the following code I am using for this:

```
 public static SSLContext getSSLContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NotFoundException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException{
    KeyStore clientCertificateKeysKeyStore = getClientCertificateKeystore();    
    KeyStore trustStore = getServerCertificateKeystore();
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(X509);    

    if(clientCertificateKeysKeyStore != null)
        kmf.init(clientCertificateKeysKeyStore, "cleint".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();


//  TrustManager[] trustManagers = {new CustomTrustManager(trustStore)};
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(X509);
    tmf.init(trustStore);

    TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
    return sslContext;

}
```

I have a PEM file from which I had to generate keystore.

```
private KeyStore loadPEMKeystoreStore(File certificateFile) throws Exception {
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(certificateFile));
        byte[] der = loadPemCertificate(caInput);
        ByteArrayInputStream derInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(der);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(derInputStream);
        String alias = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore .load(null);
        keyStore .setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        return keyStore ;
    }
```

The server certificate is a .pk12 cert stored locally.

The problem is the client certificate is not attached during handshake process. 
I have used wireshark to analyze the packet and it shows client cert length 0.

If I use .pk12 file as client certificate it is attached correctly.
But I have to use PEM file.
Any solution!!

Comment: If by '2-way' handshake you mean SSL client authentication, you need a private key for the client, not just a certificate. It is not clear what the PEM file contains, but it does look that in only contains a certificate. You need to obtain the corresponding private key and convert the key+certificate either to a PKCS#12 file or to a   keystore file (BKS for Bouncy Castle) for this to work.

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply. Actually I have already solved the problem. Your assumption is correct the PEM file was only contains a certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PEM file was only contains a certificate not the private key. Here is the updated code which is working fine.

```
  private KeyStore loadPEMKeystoreStore(File certificateFile, String password) throws Exception {
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(certificateFile));


        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_KEYSTORE_TYPE);


        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory
                .getInstance(X509);
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory
                .generateCertificate(caInput);


        keystore.load(null);
        keystore.setCertificateEntry("cert-alias", cert);
        keystore.setKeyEntry("key-alias", privateKey, password.toCharArray(),
                new Certificate[]{cert});
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        keystore.store(out, password.toCharArray());

        return keyStore ;
    }
```